# Post login website programming in PHPmySql

Tags: mysql, post, authentication

I want to create a online diary kind of website were users can login and save their images and write their memories.I have created the website and login pages in phpmysql but i dont know how individual users can login and save these details and retrieve those datas when the want to login after some time.My website works with out login i can paste images/text and retrieve those depending on date.please help me

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect to get?

Comment: soryy zerkms  i asked a vague question.sory for your trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking about sessions and saving session info to a database. This is a vague answer for a vague question:

1. Create a registration system that let's people sign up. This data should be saved to a MySQL table and should include username, password, and anything else you need.
2. Create a page in which each user can log in. This should create a session variable indicating the user and other essential information.
3. Whenever that user uploads a picture with a 'memory', add a row to another MySQL table referencing that user, the location of the photo, and the memory text.
4. Now, whenever that user logs in again... it can use their username session variable to pull all the rows from the 'photo/memories' table and can populate their page with those photos/memories.

That is how it is typically done.

Now, get to work! Good luck.

Comment: hi arkigos sorry for my vague question and thanks for this awesome reply.i am searching for this only...i have created a session and login page and mysqldatabase..can you please elaborate your answer in point 3.I am not able to understand the logic of how mysql remembers all this and add row.

Comment: Okay, you have an interface in which PHP allows them to upload a picture. Save the location of that file on the server as a PHP variable. Then, save the 'memory' text as another. Then, once they hit a 'save' button or something like that, have it execute a MySQL query that creates a new row on a table you've made for this very purpose. Have that row contain their username, then a string that indicates the location of the pic on the server, and lastly the text of the 'memory'. Then, when you are populating that users page, query all rows with that username on the table and... you get the idea

Comment: yep i understood  a little bit what you said.I have succesfully created login i made two tables one for users details and other for saving users comment and images.Its working fine thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is basically asking us to build you an entire website application. How about you first start with learning [how to build a simple login system](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-build-a-login-system-for-a-simple-website/).

Comment: hi brady thanks for the reply.arkigos gave reply to my answer..once more sorry for my vague question